# ¿Cómo se puede "bloquear" un registro de una tabla al aplicar una validación?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación móvil para controlar un grupo de ejercicios a realizar a diario. Existe un grupo de ejercicios y al día la aplicación seleccionará de manera aleatoria dos ejercicios. Lo que necesito es que los usuarios que se registren van a realizar los ejercicios que están en la segunda tabla. Lo que pretendo hacer es que cuando realice dos ejercicios diarios los bloquee así que cuando llame la tabla ejercicios solo me muestre los que le faltan hacer y no los estén bloqueados (porque ya están terminados). Si ya están bloqueados todos entonces se puede empezar nuevamente desde 0.

¿Me pueden indicar algún algoritmo o idea para implementar esto?

Aquí coloco un modelo entidad-relación del diseño actual de mis tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor delimita la pregunta. Tal como luce, es muy amplia y no tiene una respuesta concreta. Convendría explicar cuál es tu problema concreto al intentar implementar una solución para el enunciado que explicas.

Comment: lo que pretendo realizar es lo siguiente un usuario con nombre apellido documento, realice una serie de ejercicios diarios a los cuales diariamente estos ejercicios realizados los suba ala base de datos para que cuando llegue otro día muestre los ejercicios q le falta hacer y no me muestre los que realizo. solo tengo la tabla usuarios que contiene nombre apellido cédula y la tabla de ejercicios que contiene  los ejercicios que nombre  en el otro comentario lo q no se es como evaluar los ejercicios q realice si creo una tabla o que hago

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no sabes cómo evaluar los ejercicios que realice? ¿Qué necesitas implementar, qué has intentado y dónde te has atascado? Necesitamos esa información para poder ayudarte mejor. Si lo que necesitas es una especie de algoritmo para saber qué debes hacer, entonces eso es lo que debes indicar en la pregunta. Edítala adecuadamente y es muy probable que sea re abierta.

Comment: hay ya quedo planteada mejor mi duda.Si es atendible ?.

Comment: Se entiende mejor. Solo una consulta más, ¿necesitas realizar este bloqueo desde tu base de datos o desde la aplicación? ¿Qué clase de aplicación estás realizando, una web quizás?

Comment: si estoy realizando una app en android studio. lo que estoy asiendo es que un usuario realice estos ejercicios y no quiero que se repitan los ejercicios por eso los bloqueo para que no se repitan y salgan los q no a echo asta que haga todos y hay si vulva a salir si me hago entender

Comment: Lo entiendo a la perfección. Ahora que explicas más al respecto, te comento dos cosas: 1) Las aplicaciones móviles no deberían acceder a una base de datos como MySQL, sino a una base de datos más ligera como SQLite que sirve netamente como repositorio de información muy limitada y necesaria solo para la app. 2) Puede que mejor busques aplicar esta regla a nivel de aplicación y no de base de datos, es decir, que en el código de tu aplicación controles que solo deben realizarse dos ejercicios al día y verifique cuáles se han hecho y cuáles no. No sé si me explico.

Comment: la app esta con servicios a php asi  ya que no utilizo base de datos locales, pues lo que trato o supongo hacer es que al principio salgan todos los ejercicios y haga randon para que seleccione dos ejercicios  osea, que esos dos ejercicios cuando se realicen  se bloquean y los mande ala base de datos. para que cuando vaya  a realizar los ejercicios en el siguiente dia no aparezcan y aparezcan los que no ha echo ... o que me aconsejas que pueda hacer ?

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo aplicar la validación de lado de los servicios, lo cual significa que la regla está de lado de la aplicación y no de la base de datos.

Comment: lo que me quieres dar a entender es llamo los ejercicios y cuando tenga la lista me evalue los que no estan bloqueados para hacer un tipo de lista o algo asi?